# Security Error Using jQuery to POST Data Models to MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 controller with the following signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SubmitPage(PageSubmissionModel model)
{
   ...
   return Json(result);
}
```

where the return model is either a simple model:

```
public class Page 
{
    public Guid PageId { get; set; }
    public Guid SurveyId { get; set; }
    public int PageNo { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Introduction { get; set; }
}
```

or a JSON encoded url string:

```
return Json(new {
        RedirectTo = Url.RouteUrl(route.RouteName, route.RouteValues)
});
```

This controller is called from the client using the following jQuery method:

```
ajaxPost: function (responseData, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ""/Surveys/Ajax/SubmitPage",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback(data);
            }
        },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, errorMessage, exception) {
            var msg = "Problem calling " + url + "()\r\n" + errorMessage;
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

where the data argument is a JavaScript object constructed as follows:

```
responseData = {
    SurveyResponseId: 23,
    SubscriberResponseId: 47,
    PageId: 1,
    Responses: [
        {id: 24, value: "Tom" },
        ....
    ]
  };
```

When I run this code I get the following server error:

***This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request***

Researching this error (http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx) I am confused because, as far as I can see, and born out by Fiddler, the client is POSTing the JavaScript model so I don't see why the server is throwing the GET request error.  In addition, the Controller is marked with the [HttpPost] attribute.

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the whole life of your request? I suggest you to check it, through firebug for example, and confirm that the request is being made through POST and the returning error is coming when you think it's coming. Make us know the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Bardo's earlier comment, I have tracked down what is happening here.

In some circumstances, the client-script constructed data model was assigning the wrong data value to the model.  This potentially caused an uncaught exception on the server whose error message (I think) was causing the GET exception.

By tightening up the initial model validation and adding some more robust error management in the controller I was able to identify the error in the submitted model and therefore trace that back to its (JavaScript) constructor.

Ultimately, this problem demonstrates the need to be able to replicate the production environment exactly in development, I had not achieved this well enough in this instance.  Once I could replicate the problem under a debugger it was easy to identify.

Answer (score 1):

please try your code like below

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SubmitPage(PageSubmissionModel model)
{
   ...
   return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Hi Mahesh, I'm afraid I don't want to allow a GET request.  What I'm trying to establish is why the POSTed data appears to be triggering a GET security error.